# Find Duplicate Image from External Storage

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to find Duplicate Images from External Storage.
In my current solution I successfully find Duplicates.
But when the data is large, the processing time long.
My current design first gets all images, then loops to find duplicates.
Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           AllImages_1 = getImagesList();   // AllImages_1 is a array list
       }
 private ArrayList<File> getImagesList() {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data;
        ArrayList<File> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        cursor = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImages.add(new File(absolutePathOfImage));
        }
        return listOfAllImages;
    }
```

below code is find Dulpicate

```
 public void CheckedDuplicateImage() {
        int Group = 1;
        arrayList.clear();
        ArrayList<String> grpind = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < AllImages_1.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<VideoDataClass> group = new ArrayList<>();
            duplicate = false;
            boolean duplicate_I = false;
            if (grpind.contains(String.valueOf(i))) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < AllImages_1.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j && (AllImages_1.get(i).length() == AllImages_1.get(j).length() ||
                        AllImages_1.get(i).getName() == AllImages_1.get(j).getName())) {
                    if (!duplicate_I) {
                        group.add(OriginalFile(AllImages_1.get(i)));
                        duplicate_I = true;
                    }
                    duplicate = true;
                    group.add(DuplicateFile(AllImages_1.get(j)));
                    grpind.add(String.valueOf(j));

                }
            }

            if (duplicate) {
                Duplicate=true;
                String Header = "Group" + Group;
                modelClass = new ModelClass(group, Header);
                arrayList.add(modelClass);
                Group++;


            }

        }
    }

My question: **is there an alternative solution that will achieve the same result in less time?**
```